# MS Access Importing a csv Errors

Tags: ms-access, csv

Hi I am trying to import a csv and am having errors with the import. If there is a string for ex. " Hi, Hello" then it is treating it as Hi Hello in separate columns. Is there anyway to circumvent this error. For ex. how do I remove the , within " " or is there other ways. "Hi, Hello" should appear in one column not in 2 column

Comment: When you import CSV from the user interface, that wizard thing allows you to specify the text delimiter.  Is that unsatisfactory?  Or are you using a different method to import CSV?

Comment: Hi HansUp solved by saving the file as a text file instead of a csv. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the TransferText action.

If you are doing it from Access VBA code, [here is the documentation from MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx)

[And here is the link for the TransferText Macro action.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177406%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Don George Pointed out in a rejected edit: And, if using TransferText in VBA, you will need to provide a specification file (it's technically optional, but you need it in the example you gave) - I've found that the easiest way to create one is to import the file manually once, using the import proces to create and save the specification file which is where you can include then text delimiter that you need.